# Javascript: How to change get and change attributes of child elements WITHOUT using getElementById

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change the color of the clicked rows of a dynamically generated list of values with Javascript. The problem is, all the rows have the same "class" Attribute (tr.odd or tr.even, "even" or "odd" to make some css difference between the rows...) and I don't want to use IDs. So to change the color of the clicked links, I thought to get any of the attributes of (THIS) tr element, and update (add to it) a value like "clicked".. for example I have in the title-attribute everytime a different serialNr, and I can add to it "clicked" as tag, it will look like for ex. "LG 1234 clicked". And I'm not getting it.. I'm getting all the tr elements taking this tag now, so that after I click a row, the every time on "mouseleave" of another row, although it wasn't clicked, it changes its color to blue as it has been clicked, and I think this problem is due to the tag "clicked" that is added to the "title" attribute of ALL the tr elements and not specially the one I need/I clicked.

Here is the script code:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".filter-table tbody tr", function() {
        $(this).css("background", "#21374C");
        $(this).css("color", "#DFDFDF");
    }); 

$(document).on("click", ".filter-table tbody tr", function() {
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0].setAttribute("title", "clicked");
        $(this).css("color", "blue");
        $(this).css("background", "#DFDFDF");
        console.log("attribute title is: " + element.getAttribute("title"));
    });

$(document).on("mouseleave", ".filter-table tbody tr.odd", function() {
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
         if (element.getAttribute("title") == "clicked") {
            $(this).css("color", "blue");
            $(this).css("background", "#DFDFDF");   
        }
        else { 
            $(this).css("background", "#DFDFDF");
            $(this).css("color", "#222222");
        }

    });

    $(document).on("mouseleave", ".filter-table tbody tr.even", function() {
        var element = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
        if (element.getAttribute("title") == "clicked") {
            $(this).css("color", "blue");
            $(this).css("background", "#DFDFDF");   
        }
        else {
            $(this).css("background", "#FFFFFF");
            $(this).css("color", "#222222");
        }
    });
```

Example of HTML is here:

```
<tr wicket:id="content-list" class="even" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="SNr: 1"><span wicket:id="cell">1</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-MAN: AGR"><span wicket:id="cell">AGR</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-FOA: SS - MH"><span wicket:id="cell">SS - MH</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-SC: ABCDEFGH"><span wicket:id="cell">ABCDEFGH</span></td>
</tr>

<tr wicket:id="content-list" class="odd" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="SNr: 2"><span wicket:id="cell">2</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-MAN: PPT"><span wicket:id="cell">PPT</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-FOA: DB - OP"><span wicket:id="cell">DB - OP</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-SC: MNBVCXY"><span wicket:id="cell">MNBVCXY</span></td>
</tr>

<tr wicket:id="content-list" class="even" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); color: rgb(34, 34, 34); background-position: initial initial; background-repeat: initial initial;">
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="SNr: 3"><span wicket:id="cell">3</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-MAN: QWE"><span wicket:id="cell">QWE</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-FOA: AS - HG"><span wicket:id="cell">AS - HG</span></td>
     <td wicket:id="cells" title="DC-SC: LKJHGF"><span wicket:id="cell">LKJHGF</span></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You only want to change color after click or also in mouse hover and leave ??

Comment: on click, hover, and on leave back to the old colors if not clicked, and blue if clicked. but on hover I didn't copied here the script it is working fine.. should I add it?

Comment: What is `wicket:id`? Surely not standard HTML.

Comment: I thought with "var element = document.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];" I'll get the first td element of the tr, and add the tag "clicked" to the first attribute, don't mind which attribute it is, and then on mouseleave check also the first td element and its first attribute, and see if there's any "clicked" or not..

Comment: Your html is invalid, you have unclosed tags

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: it's wicket.. that means that part of code is generated through wicket/java

Comment: @php_nub_qq: because the html code is really large.. I cannot paste all of it here.. it's already much code for a question here.. the html code is 100% correct. I just pasted a little part to resume..

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria no, your HTML is **not** valid. Every first column of each row is not closed as well as the span inside it

Comment: i didnt copied all the code.. ok i will remove the first line, and as it is wasn't there.. sorry for the missunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

you are suing the JQuery Selector already, so why dont use it here?

for example:

```
 var element = $("#idName")[0].setAttribute("title", "clicked");
```

or

```
var element = $(".className")[0].setAttribute("title", "clicked");
```

br from paulq

Comment: because all the rows have the same classname: either "odd", or "even" but the content of the td elements&attributes is different as you can see in the code.. and i have thousands of rows..

Answer (score 0):

You should remove inline styling and assign classes instead.

```
$('td').click(function(){
   $(this).parent().removeClass('hover').addClass('click'); 
}).mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).parent().addClass('hover');
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).parent().removeClass('hover click');
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tp8kq/)

Of course I haven't went through your entire code. You will need to modify other changes you want to apply in your css, I'm just showing you the way. Good luck!

Comment: and "hover", "click" and "hover click" are css classes or what?

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria did you view the demo?

Comment: yes thanks.. but the problem in the demo, that the clicked style is removed after the click.. it doesnt still with that background-color.. any idea how it still "marked" so that i know which rows were already clicked..

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria well if you want it to stay then just don't remove it on mouse leave?

Comment: you're right.. did it and it works perfectly in the demo now! Don't know why it is not working in my code.. perhaps because the rows of the table are added dynamically, after the page is loaded.. ??

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria perhaps because you have inline styling left or overriding styling going on.

Comment: I think it's not working because the content we are trying to modify is loaded with ajax dynamically, after the page is loaded and that rows are created after some filter specifications are done.. but it worked with my old code.. i mean css got changed through javascript.. Weird

Comment: @KarimBelkhiria of course it wont work on loaded elements. This code runs once and applies to existing elements, if you want to add it to future elements you either have to use the `delegate` method or run this code again after loading and run it on the loaded elements only